# How to controll when Wildfly prompts for client auth cert

Tags: authentication, ssl, wildfly, openam

I am using to WildFly 9 as a container for an OpenAM demo instance. I currently have certificate based login set up and working, but I would like to be able to control when or if the browser prompts for the certificate. Is there a way to configure wildfly to only request client auth on certain OpenAM resources, for example a specific realm?

Comment: TLS/SSL client auth happens at TLS/SSL protocol layer. As TLS is between TCP and HTTP you can most likely not use a part of the request url for this decision. As long as Wilfly does not support SNI (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/XNIO-227) I does not seem to be possible.

Potentially you could frontend WildFly with Apache http server which supports SNI and use DNS alias mapping on OpenAM to use a specific FQDN for a realm. On the specific Apache http virtual host you could enable TLS client auth

Comment: Thanks Bernhard. I will give that a try